# Cannot start Eclipse - Java error

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse (Indigo) suddenly stopped working, giving the rather well-known error when trying to start it:

```
Java was starte but returned exit code=1
...
```

I've tried adding this to the eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

just before the -vmarg line.

This gets rid of the error message, but now there's just a short glimpse of the eclipse startup image, then it disappears. And eclipse doesn't start, of course.

As mentioned, this suddenly happened, without any changes to eclipse or the java installation. When the problem occured, I finally accepted the annoying Java update nag screen and installed the update.It didn't help at all.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I noticed in the eclipse.ini file these lines:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

I tried changing the version to 1.7, and even removing the two lines alltogether. Still the error message.

Here's the complete error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the backslashes with regular slashes. My eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse requires JDK bin as the virtual machine. Give path to javaw.exe as -vm argument.
my -vm argument looks like this

-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaw.exe

As you were saying this suddenly stopped working, there must be some change to JAVA_HOME or related PATH variables in your environment configuration which would have removed reference to JDK home.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I add this argument?

There must have been some changes made, yes. But since I haven't started a java application, Eclipse or other that I know of in several weeks, those changes must've been done without my knowledge.

Comment: I see that C:\Program Files\Eclipse-Indigo is the eclipse home folder. Edit eclipse.ini file in that folder. You are currently using -vm=C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe -- replace this with the javaw.exe from the JDK installation and restart eclipse.

Comment: Hm. That I don't understand. I'm editing eclipse.ini in that folder, of course, since it's the eclipse folder. But I don't understand what you mean by "You are currently using -vm=C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe"? Where am I using that? There's no mention of that in eclipse.ini...?

Comment: In the screenshot you attached, I can see that the vm argument is C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe. Eclipse is using default javaw.exe from windows installation when -vm argument was not mentioned in eclipse.ini file. Please add the line below in eclipse.ini file.
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaw.exe
// your JDK installation folder

Comment: That's what I've been trying, if you look at the other answers and comments, in all possible variations. It does nothing - the error message is still the same.

Comment: Incredible. I've reinstalled Java, tried another version of Eclipse (kepler), and tried EVERYTHING mentioned here and other places. Still it doesn't work. Man, you've gotta love Java. Not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the -vm argument to the eclipse.ini file like you did earlier, make sure you give the path to the java or javaw.exe and put the path in "" like this 
"C:\program files...." when your path has spaces

Comment: If I add quotes ("), I get this error: 
'A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll"'